# Saving position within a table before cancelling an edit?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently trying to make a cancel button function. Basically I have a customer, and the form displays their name, address, city, zip code, and state.

When I press add, it clears the form and lets me add in a new customer, BUT, if I change my mind, I can press cancel, and it should return me to the previous customer I had selected. No matter what I do, when I press cancel, it puts me on the last customer on the list, instead of the previous one I was on.

I need a way to save my position before cancelling. Is this possible? Here's what I have. How would I save my position, and then go back to access that position?

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click)

CustomersBindingSource.CancelEdit()
ComboBox1.Enabled = True
btnAdd.Enabled = True
btnDelete.Enabled = True
btnUpdate.Enabled = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I make some assumption to answer this. 
There are several option to save position, such as:

- **Tag**, any tag properties can be used Form Tag, TextBox Tag
- **Global Variable**, declared in Form scope: `Dim LastPos as Integer`
- **TextBox**, hidden and unbounded TextBox

To go back to that position use code like this:

```
 DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, LastPos
```

Hope it helps, if not please explain why and update the question..